# Stopping chrooted linux on android

Tags: android, linux

I have built myself an chrooted linux-envionment for my android-tablet and everything works fine (I can even run a desktop), but there is one thing I have not yet quite figured out: How to stop it properly...

What I want to avoid is some linux-process remaining, possibly draining the battery, so I am looking for a way to systematically kill all processes running in the chroot.

How would I do that?

Normally I start the linux-environment by starting a chrooted bash from an android terminal emulation and from that I start services or a desktop etc (depending on what I want to do), but I would need a way to cleanly shut down all the processes once I am done with the linux-session without having to reboot the tablet.

This is mainly a hacking/educational project for me, so please don't point me to some out-of-the-box solutions for running linux on android - I want to understand how it is done.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chrooted or not you shouldn't generally run Linux apps/services as root.
Create a user account in the chrooted environment and su to that user before starting an app.
When you are done kill all the processes in the system - while still under that user's privileges - naturally only that user's processes will be closed and rest will give permission denied error